# Why is Nautilus looking screwy on Ubuntu 16.04 when I try to use a theme?

Tags: nautilus, themes, 16.10

I have a pretty fresh install of Ubuntu and am trying to use some favourite themes for Unity7 ([Flatabulous](https://github.com/anmoljagetia/Flatabulous), Numix etc.). When I try to use them (switching them using Unity Tweak Tool), Nautilus starts looking screwy, like it seems to be losing buttons etc in its interface, making borders and spacings confused. Check out the address bar here, for example:

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 and Nautilus (well "Files") version 3.20.3. What might be going wrong? I want my über-modern flatness!

Comment: It has been known for a while that Flatabulous doesn't work well on 16.10. See https://github.com/anmoljagetia/Flatabulous/issues/114 for example.

Comment: @edwinksl Ah, thanks for the link! Would you have any idea what might be causing this, like what has changed in Ubuntu or Nautilus or anything else relevant that is causing this (for a few different themes I've tried)?